# Dyamic memory & Linked Lists

Tags: c++

Okay so suppose we have a linked list implementation in C++. Furthermore suppose that the node is a class and the list itself is a class and it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class List;

class Node
{
private:
    Node(char, Node*);
    char data;
    Node* next;
    friend class List;
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const List&);
};

class List
{
public:
    List(int = 0);
    List(const List&);
    ~List();
    bool gotoBeginning();
    bool gotoEnd();
    bool gotoNext();
    bool gotoPrior();
    bool insert(char);
    bool remove(char&);
    bool empty() const;
    bool full() const;
    bool clear();
    List& operator=(const List&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const List&);

private:
    Node* head;
    Node* cursor;
};

#endif
```

Suppose that the list is empty.
Furthermore, suppose we just inserted a new element, 'z', into the list which means the list has 1 node currently.

Lets take a look at the insert function:

```
bool List::insert(char item)
{
    if(empty())
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(item, NULL);
        head = cursor = newNode;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // I dont need to show this part because the above code will suffice
    }
}
```

Okay so we all know that the variable newNode which is of type pointer to node gets assigned the memory location containing the node that has been stored on the heap.

now remember we just created a new node and letts suppose that the item passed into the insert function is 'z'

```
    Memory Allocation
Stack             Heap
    |               |
    |               |
   \|/             \|/
  512               902            memory address
| -----|   |--->|-----|-----|
|  902 |   |    |  'z'| NULL|                    
|------|---|    |-----|-----|
newNode        (no name/ newNode)   variable name
```

(no name): because memory allocated on the heap can not be directly accessed other than by a pointer.

The problem I'm having is this. Is the newNode pointer created on the stack and assiged some memory address like 512 as shown above?
Or is the pointer never allocated on the stack (so just remove the 512 above) and only pointing to the memory (902) that was creted on the heap?

The reason I am asking is because the second line of code inside of the if statement inside of the insert function assigns newNode to both head and cursor

thats whats confusing me. Would head and cursor now contain address 512 or 902?

also if we were to continue and write the code inside of the else statement inside of the insert function then it would look like this:

```
bool List::insert(char item)
{
    if(empty())
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(item, NULL);
        head = cursor = newNode;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(item, NULL);
        cursor = cursor->next = newNode; // what is this line doing
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

so how does `cursor->next` get the value of new node and  `cursor` also get the value of new node.

And yes the above function works fine and I got an A on the project so all of the code is right but the concepts I mentioned are troubling me

Answer (score 1):

The pointer returned by `new` needs to be stored somewhere, and it's stored in the stack-variable `newNode`. The value of `newNode`, its contents, is the address returned by `new`.

When you assign a pointer to another pointer, it's the value of the pointer, the contents, the address the pointer points to, that is copied.

So when you do e.g.

```
head = newNode;
```

then `head` will get the same value as `newNode`, and will point to the memory allocated by the `new` expression.

---

Lets take a small example: Say you have two pointers:

```
int* a;
int* b;
```

You allocate some memory and assign to `a`:

```
a = new int;
```

Now the memory looks something like this:

```
+---+     +------------------+
| a | --> | allocated memory |
+---+     +------------------+
```

Then you assign from `a` to `b`:

```
b = a;
```

Then the memory looks something like this:

```
+---+
| a | -.
+---+  |    +------------------+
        >-> | allocated memory |
+---+  |    +------------------+
| b | -'
+---+
```

Exactly where the variables `a` and `b` are stored doesn't really matter, neither does it matter where they are pointing.

Comment: okay well that definitely does help but I'm still confused on how the cursor->next would receive the address of the newNode. and then it gets assigned newNode, cursor = newNode

Comment: @fsolano94 When the function starts, and the list is not empty, then `cursor` points to a node (supposedly the last node), which means that `cursor->next = newNode` will take the last node and make its `next` pointer point to where `newNode` is pointing. Then you take what `cursor->next` points to and assign to `cursor` making `cursor` again point to the last node in the list. There is however a problem with that expression (see next comment).

Comment: @fsolano94 The problem with `cursor = cursor->next = newNode` is that it could be evaluated either as `cursor = (cursor->next = newNode)` (which is what is expected and hoped for), but it could also be `(cursor = cursor->next) = newNode` which is *not* what you expect, and that last will cause problems. You need to explicitly add parentheses to make sure the right thing is done.

Comment: next comment? Are you posting more detials

Comment: Okay, thanks for all of your help Joachim Pileborg and awesome name btw. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = cursor->next = newNode; // what is this line doing
```

Note that assignment does not happen simultaneously. It propagates from right to left. Here is a more verbose piece of code that does the same thing as the line above:

```
Node* oldNode = cursor;
cursor = newNode;
oldNode->next = newNode;
```

under certain circumstances (overloaded assignment operators) it might even be beneficial to write it down in that order.